# Reduce recurring characters in solr query

Tags: solr, edismax

I have a document `title: vivek singh` in solr. The field type is `text_general`. When I make a query as `q=title:vivek singh`, I get this document. But if there is a slight typo like a recurring character, I get no results. For e.g. `q=title:vivvek singh` fetches no result, or `q=vvvivek singh` fetches no result. Is there a way to filter these kind of query using query analyzer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fuzzy operator](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) for that, for example:

```
   q=title:singh~0.8
```

also, you should make sure you are querying the 'title' field for all terms, so use

```
   q=title:(vivek singh)
```

Comment: I had tried fuzzy, in reality I have lot more documents with `vivek`. So I am getting some irrelevant matches. If only I could reduce `vvv` to `vv` or `v`. This specific filter will solve this use case.
Thanks for the `q=title:(vivek singh)`, completely missed it.

Comment: play with the value after ~, it affects how fuzzy the query is